# Remove old add-in from Mac Excel 2016

Tags: excel, macos

I want to remove the add-in from my the Add-in list in the Excel 2016 in MAC. I have deleted the add-in from the physical path and unchecked the add-in from the Add-in list too. Closed all the instance of Excel. When I reopen the excel, it is showing the message that "Add-in is not in the specified path. Do you want to remove the from list?. I have given Yes. Still the add-in appears in the list. Kindly help me to remove the old add-in from the list.